# What is the use of 'in' keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.2

What is the use of in keyword?

C# 7.0 introduce new keyword which is **in**. Let's share usability of this new keyword.

Comment: `in` has not been introduced in C# 7.0 but in C# 1.0 (`foreach`). New contexts have been added in C# 3.0 (LINQ), C# 4.0 (contravariance) and C# 7.2 (parameter modifier).

Answer (score 2):

C# 7 introduced the **in** modifier. It got the name by being the opposite of out keyword. It makes the reference (alias) read only; and the caller does have to initialize the value.

```
void DoSomeTask(in Employee emp)
{
    //emp can't be altered here.
}
```

It helps to restrict make any modification in object accidentally.